# how to update the jQuery setTimeout current time "tell it how many seconds remaining"?

Tags: jquery, timeout, settimeout

How do I update setTimeout current time?

for example if I have

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $( idleTimeout ).dialog("open");
},  20000);
```

Then after 5 seconds I want to tell the timer that there are only 10 seconds remaining not 15. basically skipping 5 seconds in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can update when a setTimeout function will occur by clearing the original timeout and then creating a new one.

```
// desired code to execute after timeout
var code = function() {
    $( idleTimeout ).dialog("open"); 
};

// originally set to occur after 20 secods
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, 20000);

// after 5 seconds update to run in another 10 seconds
window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  window.setTimeout(code, 10000); 
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I can't seems to figure out how to use it. I have place my code at http://jsfiddle.net/Sp4Z2/ my code should display a dialog box after 1620 seconds of idle time. Because the user can have a different tab/ browser instance that he/she actively working on I need to keep updating the counter that trigger the dialog to open. I simply send an ajax request and once that request is done then I reset the timer. But it is not working for me.  the dialog open immediately once the page finish loading

Answer (score 0):

```
// with a bit of tweak it work. change setTimeout to setInterval  
var timeoutID = window.setInterval(code, 10000);
   window.setTimeout(function() {
     window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
       window.setInterval(code, 500); 
}, 20000);
```